# How to know what tab is selected in tab control in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol

I have this program that should execute a piece of code base on the tab that is selected. How do I do it?
I've tried:

```
if tabcontrol1.tabcount=1 then
'Execute this code'

else if tabcontrol1.tabcount=2 then
'execute this code
end if
```

-But doesn't work, what's the proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `Tabcontrol_selected` event you can use the `selectedindex` property value to get the current tab.

[SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindex.aspx)